# PowerPoint (and other Office apps) keeps folder locked after closing

Tags: microsoft-office

I have been having this problem for about 10 years across various Office applications, but let me explain what I am experiencing right now. I open 4 PowerPoint files and close one of them. Now I want to rename or move the containing folder of that closed PowerPoint file. I can't, because it says it is still open, which it is not, obviously. I ran NtHandle v4.11 and find out that the folder has an handle that keeps me from moving it.

Of course I can reboot but the thing is that I have to work too. I can't reboot 100 times a day (not exaggerating). It does that almost every time. Sometimes it goes away by itself and sometimes I'm desperate and close ALL the files even though I will have to reopen them after moving the problematic folder.

Same thing with Word, since as far as i can remember (Win7+Office 2010, Win10+2010, and now 2016)

In the past I remember having success in running each file in different instance/process. It is obviously not the way MS wants me to work tough.

Please help !!

[edit] I ran some couple of tests, disabling A/V, uninstalling ALL addins. Even with two new files (empty PPT files) I was able to reproduce it. Create 2 folders with each one containing a PPT file. Open the first, open the second and close the second. It's containing folder is still locked (at least on my last 3 machines in the last 10 years). The problem doesn't exist if you open the first and second and then close the first. It will be unlocked properly.

Comment: This a local or network drive?  This a protected or unprotected folder?  I have been using Office for 20 years, 10 years as a student in some capacity, the other as a professional engineer and I have never in all those years ran into this problem.

Comment: Local, unprotected, no disk-encryption, no weird NTFS permissions configured. Only notable thing I can say is that I use 2 COM add-ins but I can reproduce the problem with those add-ins disabled.

Comment: Next time it happens use [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find which process is locking the file (use the search icon). It's also possible that this is your antivirus locking the file, or some context-indexing product, so check if it happens when booting in Safe mode.

Comment: @harrymc I think I already figured out with NtHandle that it is PowerPoint PID that is locking the folder with an OS handle. I double checked with Process Explorer and it gives me the same PID. I think Process Explorer use NtHandle under the hood, so same results.

Comment: Does it happen when booting in Safe mode?

Comment: @harrymc Can't start Word or PowerPoint from safe mode : "We couldn't start your programe", error code 0x426-0x0. Upon a clean reboot the problem is not present. I will try to be careful and pinpoint when it starts to happen. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're *closing* the file, not just minimizing it?

It seems MS Office is not *actually* closing when you attempt to close it. Check to see if the app is still open. Open one file, close MS Office (not minimize it), then:

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd> to open *Task Manager*.
- Go to the *Details* tab.
- Click on the column header *Name*. to sort by app name.
- Look for any Office app that is *still* running, though you tried to close it.

There are a few things you can do to avoid rebooting; any of these should work.

- Work on one or two files at a time and then completely close Office, not just the individual document files.
- Kill any remnant Office process using *Task Manager*.
- Use a third-party tool, such as free [LockHunter](https://lockhunter.com/), to unlock the file.
- Best would be to correct the root cause, perhaps an improperly installed Office suite or an add-on causing the issue. Reinstall MS Office, if you still have the licensed media.
- If you cannot reinstall, try a free office suite, such as [LibreOffice](https://www.libreoffice.org/), that offers all the functionality of MS Office.

Comment: There is no way I can be confused between minimizing and closing :) PowerPoint actually do liberate the low level OS handle on the file, just not the folder. I have constraints on the work I do and can't use LibreOffice for that, but I actually use it for other stuff. I know about LockHunter and how to kill the handle. I just don't want to do that since I have seen cases when the folder is recreated afterward, after I renamed/moved it.

Comment: Do you have *two* PowerPoint files in the same folder, one of which is closed, but the other is open? BTW, also show *Hidden* files in Explorer, and see if there are .lck files in the folder you're trying to move.

Comment: impossible, my work structure is always the same thing. Each folder always contains only 2 files, one office file (word or powerpoint) and the accompanying generated PDF, which is not the problem since it is not locked as per the info I see in ProcessExplorer and NtHandle. I can delete the PDF, the Office file but still can't rename the outer folder when it's empty ! And yes, I checked hidden files :|

Answer (score 0):

Right now, the only way I was able to make it work is by using IObit Unlocker, which is a shame to have to rely on a closed source 3rd party shareware to work around what definitely looks like a bug from my perspective.